# Mongoose Schema Type optionals

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been looking around for a while, and I cannot seem to find a definitive list of mongoose schema type optional keywords (I don't know if this is the proper term for them, which is probably part of my confusion).  For example:

```
var movie = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: false}
})
```

Here, the movie has a title which is required and not lowercase.  Where can I find a full list of the optionals?  By optionals, I mean the things like 'required', 'lowercase', etc.

Other types don't have things like 'lowercase' so is there a list of which ones apply to strings, numbers, arrays, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have assembled a list myself by walking through their documentation.

Array:

- required - minimum of 1 element (empty array not valid)

String:

- required - string must be given (`""` is valid)
- lowercase - lowercases each character in the string
- match: [regex] - match the string to the provided regex
- maxlength: n - the maximum length for the string
- minlenght: n - the minimum length for the string
- trim - remove leading/trailing whitespace
- uppercase - upcases each character in the string

Number:

- required - number must be given
- max: n - maximum value for the number
- min: n - minimum value for the number

Date:

- required - date must be given
- expires: n - the field expires after n seconds (see documentation)
- max: "yyyy-mm-dd" - the date bust be before the parameter
- min: "yyyy-mm-dd" - the date bust be after the parameter

Boolean:

- required - must be true or false